# "Have been through" or "have gone through"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I don't know whether *been* or *gone* would be better in this sentence:

> I have some long-lasting memories in my mind, such as memorable overseas trips that I have **been** through.
>
> I have some long-lasting memories in my mind, such as memorable overseas trips that I have **gone** through.

Comment: Neither is "natural" English. They're trips you've *been **on*** (or less commonly, but still validly, *gone on*). Or just *trips I've **had/taken***.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These sentences both have perfectly acceptable grammar, but the intended meaning is not entirely clear. Consider this phrasing:

> I have some long-lasting memories in my mind, such as memorable overseas trips that I have taken.

The phrases "been through" and "gone through" both can be used to imply enduring hardship or undergoing stress. People use them in sayings like "He looks like he's been through hell" or "I can't believe I had to go through that" or "Don't make me go through that again." This puts a negative connotation on the phrases.

If the overseas trips were **negative experiences**, if they went badly and are not fond memories, that phrasing is perfectly suitable.

If the overseas trips with **enjoyable experiences**, saying you "took" a trip is more common and clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is more an editing chore than a 'right/wrong' problem. For brevity one should cut out the redundancies. 'memories' are long-lasting. That's the nature of memories.'Memories' are also 'in the mind'. That is the proper location of memories. If one has memories of a trip--it's understood that a trip was taken (gone through; been through).

If a news sub-editor were looking at this copy, he would cross out 'long-lasting', 'in my mind', 'memorable' and 'that I have taken (been through; gone through)'. The final edited version would read: 'I have memories of trips overseas.' 'Trips overseas' is better than having memories of' overseas trips' since it highlights 'trips' rather than emphasizing the particular type of trip. This edited version may seem bland in content, but no worse than the original. The sentence is just a brief intro to strange happenings on these trips.